# QCD vs. QED gauge invariance

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, gauge-invariance

Trying to understand the difference between QED and QCD gauge invariance treatment I found the following paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.3425

I have the following questions:

1. I understand Eq. (42) as the Taylor expansion of the S matrix (scattering matrix = exponential of 4-D integral of interaction Lagrangian, $e^{i\int d^4x\ {\cal L}_{interaction}}$) until order 2 because any other order will give you a zero when evaluating
   among initial and final state. So, why is a
   current that is not the one in Eq. (10) used in Eq. (44) ? Eq. (10) gives the current
   that will appear in the interaction Lagrangian, so it will be in the
   amplitude calculus.
2. Following this argument, my second question is
   about Eq. (48) where it is suggested that $M_\mu$ comes out of $J_\mu$ only.
   But will not Eq. (48) be directly zero due to the reasoning for the
   first question? Could you tell me how to understand that result?

Comment: It would be good if OP (or somebody else?) could try to make the question formulation self-contained, so one doesn't have to open the link to understand the question. Also please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.

Comment: I think this way is better because it in not necessary to read the whole document, you just have to look at the equations I mentioned. Moreover, the paper has a great relevance information about the QCD gauge invariance treatment that I think could be useful for everybody taking into account that in many books this is lightly developed